# Extract specific columns from delimited file (long row to next line)

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk, scripting

Want to extract 2 columns from delimited file **(delimiter '||')** in unix can be easily be done if complete row in on one line like below

```
foo||bar||baz||quux
```

by

```
cut -d'||' -f1 file_name
```

but in my case records in file for a single row record went to next line for example:

```
foo||bar||baz||quux||foo||bar||baz||quux||foo||bar||baz||quux
||quux||bar||baz||quux||foo||bar||baz||quux||foo||bar||baz||quux
```

and its output from above command is

```
foo
quux
```

instead should be just "foo" because it is in first column.

file contain in row 1

```
foo||bar||baz||quux||foo||bar||baz||quux||foo||bar||baz||quux
||quux||bar||baz||quux||foo||bar||baz||quux||foo||bar||baz||quux
```

file contain in row 2

```
foo2||bar2||baz2||quux2||foo2||bar2||baz2||quux2||foo2||bar2||baz2||quux2
||quux2||bar2||baz2||quux2||foo2||bar2||baz2||quux2||foo2||bar2||baz2||quux2
```

output should be

```
foo
foo2
```

Comment: Oh dear, please edit that into readable format.

Comment: I tried to restate my question which where wrongly understood !

Comment: Re "*wrongly understood*":  If you're running *Linux*, then the `cut` command is from *GNU coreutils*.  But *GNU*'s `cut -d '||'` returns the error "*cut: the delimiter must be a single character*", this implies the OP code shown must not be accurate.  If that's true, then please correct the post to show the actual code that's being run.

Answer (score 0):

Almost, but the `-d` switch only takes one char:

```
cut -d'|' -f1 file_name
```

Output:

```
foo
foo2
```

---

Note: since the delimiters are doubled, the `-f` switch won't work as expected if the field number is greater than *1*.  One way to handle that is adjust the field to equal "*2n-1*".  So to get field *#3*, do `-f$(( (3*2) - 1 ))`.

Comment: I tried to restate my question which where wrongly understood !

Answer (score 0):

Using awk. Since it's the first field of every other record (`NR%2`), use:

```
$ awk -F\| 'NR%2{print $1}' file
foo
foo2
```

Data (four records):

```
$ cat file
foo||bar||baz||quux||foo||bar||baz||quux||foo||bar||baz||quux
||quux||bar||baz||quux||foo||bar||baz||quux||foo||bar||baz||quux
foo2||bar2||baz2||quux2||foo2||bar2||baz2||quux2||foo2||bar2||baz2||quux2
||quux2||bar2||baz2||quux2||foo2||bar2||baz2||quux2||foo2||bar2||baz2||quux2
```

Interesting phenomenon is that mawk accepts `-F"\|\|"` (dual pipes) as delimiter but GNU awk doesn't.